# More Viewcontroller.m/.h?

Tags: ios, xcode

For my IOS app, i am using a tab bar controller on a mainstoryboard. I would like to have 4 tabs in total. How do i add more view controller .h's and .m's to allow me to code on these new tabs?

Thanks

Comment: I am not an iOS programmer, but to just get the new controllers, do CMD+N, create a new Objective-C class and choose NSViewController in the dropdown menu

Comment: Yes, but on iOS the class is UIViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a new UIViewController subclass to your project either press CMD+N or go to File --> New --> New File. In the left pane select Cocoa Touch under the iOS header and select UIViewController subclass. Press next and name your new class. Make sure it's a subclass of UIViewController and not UITableViewController. Hit next again. Then alloc init the new view controller and add it to your tab bar.